# How to set the root dir of an html page?

Tags: html

I'm in the following directory on my server:

- http://example.nl/cms/components/

Components are in .phtml files but the extension is removed by htaccess rules.

Now I want to go to another .phtml file but then I have to write this:

```
<a href="../other-page/"></a>
```

I noticed I can also just do this:

```
<a href="/other-page/"></a>
```

But then it won't go to http://example.nl/cms/other-page/ as I want, but to http://example.nl/other-page/

How can I change the document root to `"cms"` so that I only have to use a single `"/"`?

Comment: You could use [`$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) to produce absolute paths. If you really want to change the location of root, you'll have to reconfigure your server.

Comment: I suppose you could add a `<base>` element to your HTML header. If you add `<base href="http://example.nl/cms/">` to the `<head>` section, then any link pointing to `/other-page/` should actually go to `http://example.nl/cms/other-page/`.

Comment: @rickdenhaan That's amazing, I didn't know this existed. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Here is what you need. You need to set the meta tag **basedir**:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="http://example.nl/cms/">
  </head>
  <body>
    <a href="/other-page/">click me</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

And then the browser knows that by `/other-page/` you want to link to `/cms/other-page/`.

This is [supported in all browsers](https://caniuse.com/?search=base) as you can see.